# Do functions that convert data into lists use more memory?

Tags: python, loops, memory, data-structures

***I'm aware datetime would serve as an effective way to resolve this problem, but I'm still a beginner and would like to understand why this code isn't displaying the desired output**

The following code produced an error message stating that the program used 13 CPU seconds so it was ended.

I don't understand why this code would take up so much memory, originally the functions below didn't convert their inputs into a list, but I did that so we could alter each parameter until the condition in IsBefore returned False, which would end the while loop and return an updated "number_of_days" for the total iterations of the nextDay function on start_date.

Edit: I converted the items into lists because I wasn't sure if

```
year1, month1, day1 = nextDay(year1,month1,day1)
```

Would properly update those values

```
def nextDay(year, month, day):
    """Simple version: assume every month has 30 days"""
    date=[year,month,day]
    if date[2] < 30:
        return [year, month, day + 1]
    else:
        if date[1] == 12:
            return [year + 1, 1, 1]
        else:
            return [year, month + 1, 1]

def IsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    Before=[year1,month1,day1]
    Current=[year2,month2,day2]
    if (Before[0]>Current[0]) or (Before[0]==Current[0] and Before[1]>Current[1]) or (Before[0]==Current[0] and Before[1]==Current[1] and Before[2]>Current[2]):
        return False
    else:
        return True

def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    number_of_days=0
    start_date=[year1,month1,day1]
    while IsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2)==True:
        start_date=nextDay(year1,month1,day1)
        number_of_days+=1
    return number_of_days


def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,9,30,2012,10,30),30), 
                  ((2012,1,1,2013,1,1),360),
                  ((2012,9,1,2012,9,4),3)]

    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print "Test with data:", args, "failed"
        else:
            print "Test case passed!"

test()
```

Comment: What is the problem now, too much CPU time needed or too much memory needed?

Comment: too much CPU time needed; that's what produced the error. Wouldn't the memory usage affect the CPU time required to run the program?

Comment: Depending on the computer you use just counting up day by day needs some time although this must be a rather old machine to take so long for about 400 iterations.

Comment: @ChandlerScott no, not necessarily. There are memory inefficient ways of doing things that are *very fast*, and memory efficient ways of doing things that are slow. It totally depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I converted the items into lists because I wasn't sure if
>
> ```
> year1, month1, day1 = nextDay(year1,month1,day1)
> ```
>
> Would properly update those values

You have it exactly *backwards*. Now when you do:

```
start_date=[year1,month1,day1]
while IsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2)==True:
    start_date=nextDay(year1,month1,day1)
    number_of_days+=1
return number_of_days
```

Then `year1, month1, day1` are never affected, and you continually pass the same valeus to `while IsBefore(...)` which might explain why your code isn't doing what you want.

Consider:

```
>>> x, y, z = 1, 2, 3
>>> def f(): return 42, 88, 99
...
>>> a_list = [x, y, z]
>>> a_list = f()
>>> a_list
(42, 88, 99)
>>> x, y, z
(1, 2, 3)
```

Your program is taking too long because you've created an infinite loop, not because of memory.

Also, as an aside, unless there's a good reason for you to be using Python 2, e.g. your boss is making you, you are maintaining a working code base that is in Python 2, or your professor is making you, then you should really be learning Python 3.